# Join values in one table only when the minimum value is less than value in other table - snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have two tables:

### Table A

| Purchase_date | Product_ID |
| --- | --- |
| 20200101 | 1 |
| 20190101 | 2 |
| 20200301 | 1 |
| 20201201 | 2 |

### Table B

| Product_ID | Price | Price_change_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 20191231 |
| 2 | 15 | 20201031 |
| 1 | 12 | 20200110 |
| 1 | 20 | 20201231 |
| 2 | 8 | 20190331 |

I want to join these two tables based on two criteria:

1. If the purchase_date < min(price_change_date), return the price corresponding to the min(price_change_date)
2. Else return the price at the max(price_change_date) that is less than the purchase_date

I have written a query to successfully get results for the second criteria, but not the first, and I'm not sure if they can be combined within the same query.

Results for the above table should yield:

### Results

| Purchase_date | Product_ID | Price | Price_change_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20200101 | 1 | 10 | 20191231 |
| 20190101 | 2 | 8 | 20190331 |
| 20200301 | 1 | 12 | 20200110 |
| 20201201 | 2 | 15 | 20201031 |

Notice the second row is the one that returns a price with a purchase date that precedes the price_change_date.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a lateral join:

```
select a.*, b.*
from a, lateral
     (select b.*
      from b
      where b.product_id = a.product_id and b.price_change_date <= a.purchase_date
     order by b.price_change_date desc
     limit 1
    ) b;
```

EDIT:

The above gives you the most recent price change information.  If you want records in `a` before the original price, then you can use:

```
select a.*
from a left join
     (select b.product_id, min(b.price_change_date) as min_price_change_date
      from b
      group by product_id
     ) b
     on a.purchase_date < b.price_change_date;
```

Comment: Hi Gordon, I think this answers the first criteria, but not the second.  Nevertheless, when I attempted this in snowflake, I am receiving an error: SQL compilation error: Unsupported subquery type cannot be evaluated

Comment: @SeanG17 . . . That is what the `order by` does.

Comment: I am still getting the SQL error.  The other issue is that these results will also give me prices of those products with a price associated with a price_change_date that precedes the purchase date.  I only want to use the prices of products that have the earliest price_change_date AFTER the purchase date.

Comment: @SeanG17 . . . I misunderstood the question.